# CustomRenderer iOS for button TouchUpInside change background

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to write a CustomRenderer for iOS through which I want to change the `BackgroundColor` of the button when the user touches it. So far i got this:

```
public class BtnRendereriOS : ButtonRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);


        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(3, 169, 244);
            Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 0;

        }
        Control.TouchUpInside += (sender, UIButton) => {
            Control.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown;
        };


    }
}
```

Its not working however. I guess there needs to be some sort of eventhandler in order to make this possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background colors needs to be initially set (if not the default color), then you need to set it back to that same color on `TouchUpInside` and `TouchUpOutside`. On `TouchDown`, set it to the color that you wish it to be while the button is being pressed.

#### Toggle background color:

```
if (Control != null)
{
    void BackgroundNormalState(object sender)
    {
        (sender as UIButton).BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
    }
    BackgroundNormalState(Control);
    Control.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        BackgroundNormalState(sender);
    };
    Control.TouchUpOutside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        BackgroundNormalState(sender);
    };
    Control.TouchDown += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        (sender as UIButton).BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
    };
}
```

#### Update:

> Can i change my textcolor through this methodgroup as well?

There are is a `SetTitleColor` where you can assign different colors to the different `UIControlState` values, `Normal` and `Highlighted` are the ones to start with:

```
Control.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Red, UIControlState.Normal);
Control.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Green, UIControlState.Highlighted);
```

Comment: Thank you! Can i change my textcolor through this methodgroup as well?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time @SushiHangover ! It works, however, there is a transition element on top of the button, meaning that the background instantly changes color while the text has an opacity transition.

Comment: @JeppeChristensen If the "animation" is not needed, you can use `UIView.PerformWithoutAnimation` to set the `SetTitleColor` and `BackgroundColor` (do this within the TouchDown/TouchUp), or if you are trying to match the animation `UIView.Animate|UIView.AnimateAsync` and change the BackgroundColor and TitleColor in the Action of that method so the color transition is animated from|to during the same period of time. Consult the `Core Animation` docs for more info on that.

Comment: @JeppeChristensen no problem, if you get stuck on that, just ask a new question.. ;-)